# Cómo redirigir a la vista de formulario de un modelo desde un controlador sin pasar por la vista de autenticación

Tags: autenticación, odoo16

estoy haciendo un trabajo en odoo 16 como parte de un proyecto de mi trabajo y necesito, a partir de una URL, que el usuario acceda a la vista de la funcionalidad sin pasar por la parte de la autenticación para ello tengo hecho esto:

```
from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request

class RestAPI(http.Controller):
  
  @http.route('/client_document/<id>/<token>', auth='public', type='http', methods=['GET','POST'])
  def api_show_client_document(self, id, token, **kwargs):

      user_id = request.env['res.users.apikeys']._check_credentials(scope='odoo.web', key=token)
      if not user_id: return 'invalid token'
      request.update_env(user=user_id)
      url = '/web#id=%s&view_type=form&model=client.document' % id
      return request.redirect(url)
```

el problema es que siempre me está direccionando para la página de autenticación y no es lo que se desea de qué manera puedo hacer que odoo reconozca que ya el usuario lo autentico yo por abajo dado el token y le deje acceder directamente al modelo cuyo id se especifica, por favor alguien que pueda ayudarme, gracias